# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning even though wrapped in try/catch()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting the following error message when trying to run `storeDirectory()`.

Why doesn't my `catch()` statement not catch the error that is thrown inside `addFile()`?

My understanding is that errors bubble up to any "outer" catch statement but that doesn't seem to be the case in my code.

```
(node:21204) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: HTTP error 500
    at addFile (/Users/joe/dev/node/db/dbFunctions.js:28:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:21204) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```

```
//dbFunctions.js
...
const addFile = async (name, type, href) => {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3002/files", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      name,
      type,
      href
    }),
  });
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
  }
  return response.json();
};
```

```
//app.js
const { addFile } = require("./db/dbFunctions");
...
const storeDirectory = async () => {
  try {
    //create array of files
    const response = await getDirectory();
    const arr = response.directory.items;

    //loop through array and add each item to database
    arr.map((item) => {
      //add item to DB
      addFile(
        item.name,
        item.type,
        item.href
      );
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`try` will only catch asynchronous errors if the Promise is `await`ed. Change

```
arr.map((item) => {
  //add item to DB
  addFile(
    item.name,
    item.type,
    item.href
  );
});
```

to

```
await Promise.all(arr.map((item) => 
  //add item to DB
  addFile(
    item.name,
    item.type,
    item.href
  );
));
```

making sure to return the Promise from the `.map`.

Comment: Still getting the same @certainperformance

Comment: Are you sure you `await`ed the `Promise.all` call, and that you're returning the `addFile` call from inside the mapper? If you do, the error really should be caught. Double check your code.

Comment: Ah, I missed returning addFile. Removed the { and it works. Thanks again!